# How to implement ViewModel if I am using Razor Pages with no Controller

Tags: asp.net, t-sql, mvvm, viewmodel, razor-pages

Or am I required to use a controller? I have a Movies Class, a Genres Class, and a Media class that I will need to combine in a Model View so that I can have access to multiple models on my Razor Page. I've seen a lot of documentation for the Model-View-ViewModel pattern, but they all seem to revolve around using Controllers.

ViewModel Class, located in a seperate folder entitled "ViewModel"

```
namespace MyMovies.Models
{
    public class MoviesModelView
    {
        public List<Movies> Movies { get; set; }
        public List<Media> Media { get; set; }
        public List<Genres> Genres { get; set; }
        public List<TitleType> TitleType { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Example of my Genres Model. My other classes (for Media, Movies for instance) are similar, except they have different fields of course.

```
namespace MyMovies.Models
{
    public class Genres
    {
        [Key]
        public byte GenreID { get; set; }
        public String GenreName { get; set; }
        public String ImageURL { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have attempted to create a RazorPage scaffold that combines code from each of these classes really. But I cant scaffold without having a primary Key. And when I scaffold without entity framework, it says that my page cannot be found. Is there any documentation on creating the MVVM pattern with razor pages (no controller)?

Answer (score 10):

The [PageModel class in Razor Pages](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/pagemodel) is considered to act as a combined controller and ViewModel. By default, it is exposed to its Content Page (analogous to an MVC view) via the `@model` directive. You can either add properties to your PageModel for each of the items wrapped in your ViewModel:

```
public class MyPageModel : PageModel
{
    public List<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Or you can just add your ViewModel as a property:

```
public class MyPageModel : PageModel
{
    public MoviesModelView ViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

In the first example, you reference stuff in the content page as you would expect:

```
@foreach(var movie in Model.Movies)
{

}
```

In the second, it's a little more messy (to me, anyway):

```
@foreach(var movie in Model.ViewModel.Movies)
{

}
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this. What about scaffolding my razor page without a primary key?

Comment: how do you return the model?

Comment: @inno I'm not at all clear what you are asking. I suggest posting your own question with some more details on what you are after and what you have tried.

Comment: Well i tried returning the model by putting it as a param inside the OnPost() function. But if u put the pagemodel in there, it will fail. It turns out you dont need to do that. The changes are right on the model, no need to return anything...

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the reply provided by [Mike Bind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55965716/7389293), you could also add on top of your Razor Page view, code like the following:

```cs
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "My Page";
    var movies = Model.ViewModel.Movies;
}
```

And when looping through the movies:

```cs
@foreach (var movie in movies)
{
    // code
}
```

That way, you can make switch easily the implementation you apply in the view, in case you want to go back to `var movies = Model.Movies;`

Also, keep in mind that the use of a single view model, will allow you to replace 10 properties/objects, for example, for 1 single class (ViewModel).

```cs
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    public IList<CrewMember> Crew { get; set; }
    // Other properties you may need
}
```

In favor of using view models:

- I'd count reusability of that class later anywhere in the project.
- View models provide an alternative way to prevent overposting. As explained in [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/crud?view=aspnetcore-6.0#view-model).

Drawback:

- In the Page model, you'll have to do more work assigning the actual values to the variables.

At the end of the day, your final selection will depend on your preferences, your project scope and your work time constraints.